# OCR Extraction ( business card)

Tags: flutter, ocr, tesseract

I'm new to flutter and trying to build an flutter based app that scans a business card then extracts the information, I'm already half way there but sometimes it doesn't extract correctly, sometimes is doesn't display the extracted text in its corresponding field .. if anyone has and answer , i highly appreciate it!!

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tesseract_ocr/flutter_tesseract_ocr.dart';

class RecognizePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? path;
  const RecognizePage({Key? key, this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RecognizePage> createState() => _RecognizePageState();
}

class _RecognizePageState extends State<RecognizePage> {
  bool _isBusy = false;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  String name = '';
  final nameFieldController = TextEditingController();

  String function = '';
  final functionFieldController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController societeFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController adresse1FieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController adresse2FieldController = TextEditingController();

  String number = '';
  final numeroFieldController = TextEditingController();

  final emailFieldController = TextEditingController();

  String website = '';
  final websiteFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    processImage(widget.path!);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Recognized Page")),
      body: _isBusy
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Nom et prénom'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        name = value;
                      },
                      controller: nameFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Fonction'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        function = value;
                      },
                      controller: functionFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Société'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      controller: societeFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Adresse 1'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      controller: adresse1FieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Adresse 2'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      controller: adresse2FieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Numéro'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        number = value;
                      },
                      controller: numeroFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Email'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                      controller: emailFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Text('Site Web'),
                    TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        website = value;
                      },
                      controller: websiteFieldController,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        saveForm();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Save'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  void processImage(String imagePath) async {
    print('Image path: $imagePath');

    setState(() {
      _isBusy = true;
    });

    try {
      final text = await FlutterTesseractOcr.extractText(imagePath);
      setState(() {
        controller.text = text;
        extractInformation(text);
        print(text);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }

    setState(() {
      _isBusy = false;
    });
  }

  void extractInformation(String text) {
    final name = extractName(text);
    final function = extractFunction(text, name);
    final societe = extractSociete(text);
    final adresse1 = extractAdresse1(text);
    final adresse2 = extractAdresse2(text);
    final numero = extractNumero(text);
    final email = extractEmail(text);
    final website = extractWebsite(text);

    nameFieldController.text = name;
    functionFieldController.text = function;
    societeFieldController.text = societe;
    adresse1FieldController.text = adresse1;
    adresse2FieldController.text = adresse2;
    numeroFieldController.text = numero;
    emailFieldController.text = email;
    websiteFieldController.text = website;
  }

  String extractName(String text) {
    final namePattern = RegExp(r'[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+');
    final match = namePattern.firstMatch(text);
    if (match != null) {
      return match.group(0)!;
    }
    return '';
  }

  String extractFunction(String text, String name) {
    final lines = text.split('\n');

    final nameLineIndex = lines.indexWhere((line) => line.contains(name));
    if (nameLineIndex != -1 && nameLineIndex < lines.length - 1) {
      final functionLineIndex = nameLineIndex + 1;
      final functionLine = lines[functionLineIndex].trim();
      final commonWords = ['and', 'the', 'of', 'in', 'at', 'on'];
      final functionWords = functionLine.split(' ');
      final filteredWords = functionWords
          .where((word) => !commonWords.contains(word.toLowerCase()));

      final jobTitle = filteredWords.join(' ');

      return jobTitle.trim();
    }

    return '';
  }

  String extractSociete(String text) {
    return 'Company name';
  }

  String extractAdresse1(String text) {
    return 'adress';
  }

  String extractAdresse2(String text) {
    return 'adress';
  }

  String extractNumero(String text) {
    final phoneNumberPattern =
        RegExp(r"^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$");

    final match = phoneNumberPattern.firstMatch(text);
    if (match != null) {
      return match.group(0)!;
    }

    return '';
  }

  String extractEmail(String text) {
    return 'Email';
  }

  String extractWebsite(String text) {
    final websitePattern = RegExp(
        r"^(http:)|(https:)|(www){1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6}\b(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)$");
    final match = websitePattern.firstMatch(text);
    if (match != null) {
      return match.group(0)!;
    }
    return '';
  }

  void saveForm() {
    final name = nameFieldController.text;
    final function = functionFieldController.text;
    final societe = societeFieldController.text;
    final adresse1 = adresse1FieldController.text;
    final adresse2 = adresse2FieldController.text;
    final numero = numeroFieldController.text;
    final email = emailFieldController.text;
    final website = websiteFieldController.text;

    print('Name: $name');
    print('Function: $function');
    print('Societe: $societe');
    print('Adresse 1: $adresse1');
    print('Adresse 2: $adresse2');
    print('Numéro: $numero');
    print('Email: $email');
    print('Website: $website');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inapp_flutter_kyc](https://pub.dev/packages/inapp_flutter_kyc) package. For Business Card Scanning, you can consider two cases, where the keyword(Name/id/address) and value are inline and the keyword and the value are in the next line.

In `EkycServices().openImageScanner()` function, pass a map of keyword name and a boolean value as argument ->
For example

```
Map<String, bool> keyWordData = {
    'Name' : false,
    'Date of Birth' : true,
    'NID No' : false
  };
```

-> If the keyword and the value are **inline** pass true (In same row)

-> if the keyword and the value are not inline pass false. (In next row)

Now pass this keyWordData to EkycServices().openImageScanner()

```
ExtractedDataFromId? extractedDataFromId;
extractedDataFromId = await EkycServices().openImageScanner(keyWordData);
```

Thus you can get the item names and its corresponding value. Let me know if it helps. `extractedDataFromId?.keywordNvalue` contains a map having keyword and value. Go through the package's exmaple and you can get a clear idea. Let me know if that helps.